# color property for ElevatedButton Widget throws an error

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

Here's my code:

[image: color is underined red.]

```
body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Hi Mom!'),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {  },
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              child: Text('Hi Dad!'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

It shows the error:

```
The named parameter 'color' isn't defined.
```

I also did `flutter clean` and Invalidate Caches and  Restart, doesn't seem to work.

flutter --version:

```
Flutter 2.10.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision db747aa133 (11 days ago) • 2022-02-09 13:57:35 -0600
Engine • revision ab46186b24
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you. Refer **`ElevatedButton`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html)

```
ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Hi Dad!'),
    ),
```

Your result-> [image]

Comment: I was following a tutorial from 2019. Thank you this helped.

Comment: @neversettleevolve `color: Colors.deepPurple,` is work in `RaisedButton()` but now `RaisedButton()` is deprecated by flutter team you can used `ElevatedButton()` Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

### Use this: `MaterialStateProperty`

The purpose of `MaterialStateProperty` is to make it possible to specify different styles for different states
i.e.,

```
        TextButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.redAccent),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0))),
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.deepOrangeAccent)),
            onPressed: () {
            //
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Hiii',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ))
```